# Overleaf template not compatible with texshop

Tags: xetex, fontspec, overleaf, texshop

I would like to make use of this template from overleaf and work on it offline on Texshop.

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/prometheuscv/hhkdyvbtvhsq

Unfortunately, Texshop can't compile it with XeLatex. One of the messages I get is the following:

l.27 kpathsea:make_tex: Invalid filename `Cormorant Garamond Regular', contains ' '

./main.tex:27: Package fontspec Error: The font "Cormorant Garamond Regular" ca
nnot be (fontspec) found.

Comment: you may need the font installed eg from https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Cormorant+Garamond

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
Do you know by any chance how to get it installed so that texshop can make use of it?

Comment: you can put it in the current directory or install it in your system eg in windows just drop it in the fonts directory. (texshop doesn't need the font but xelatex will find any system installed font)

Comment: Thank you David! It does work smoothly now.

I installed the font using "Open Font Book" for mac. Take care!

Comment: I know nothing about macs, you could post a self answer so you use the right words:-)

Answer (score 1):

The issue was just about having the font installed.

As suggested by @David Carlisle, "Cormorant Garamond" can be downloaded at [fonts.google.com/specimen/Cormorant+Garamond](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Cormorant+Garamond).

After download, unzip the file and add the font package to your operative system. For mac computers open the app "Font Book", select "add new font" (the + sign) and choose the whole folder unzipped. This will make the font available for XeLatex and compiling will be smooth.